# What iOS Twitter apps support custom API URLs?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, twitter

I recently read about the [WordPress.com Twitter API](http://en.support.wordpress.com/twitter-api/) released in 2009, and I want to test it out.

The API requires you to use a Twitter client that supports custom API URLs.  The example iOS application that they listed was Tweetie2, but it's dead now.

Are there any other iOS app that allow custom API URLs to that I can test this out?

Comment: please note, my question is not related to the iOS custom URL scheme to open apps (like twitter:// and tweetbot://). It is related to using a twitter app as a way to access the Wordpress API as given on the page I've linked. Essentially, there's an API endpoint at twitter-api.wordpress.com that I want the twitter client to assume is my default twitter server and to connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

Tweetbot for iOS does. It relies on the "tweetbot://" prefix. Using it without a suffix launches the app. But you can also tack on things like "timeline" to load up a users own timeline (the full command would be as follows `tweetbot:///timeline`). Other commands are `tweetbot:///post?text=hello` which will tweet "hello" or `tweetbot://cksum/post` which will tweet with a username (in this case "cksum"). Others include things like search or pull up a user's profile.

Comment: cksum, this is not at all what I want. If you read the wordpress twitter API, it is the concept that we can use a twitter tool to login to workpress and read the blogs we follow in a 'wordpress timeline' and also post to wordpress from the app, essentially making wordpress a micro-blogging tool. 

What you've given me as an answer is not related to my question at all. Thanks for the effort though, I am fully aware of the URL based opening of sections of apps in iOS.